# CentOS 8 server: /bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: linux, centos8, make, custom-errors

I get an error running make. I have never seen this error. There are no other errors except this one. I am seriously baffled.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show full `ld` command line and error message.

Comment: The error message is in the title. What do you mean with ld command line? I am new to linux.

Comment: Then you need to involve a more experienced colleague.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have been able to fix this. It was a missing line of code in CMakeLists.txt in the failing program. Had to put in "link_libraries_(stdc++fs)".